# Android EditText not expanding with multiline

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, multiline, android-inputtype

I have EditText in a chat layout, that is supposed to expand when the user is typing more than one line.
I used `android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"` but it's not working.
I tried to use `android:singleLine="false"` and

```
write_et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)
write_et.setSingleLine(false)
```

but it's still not working.
This is my code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.improve.myproject.fragments.ChatFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/send_btn"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/send_btn"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/send_shape"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:contentDescription="to info"
                android:tooltipText="@string/take_out_frustration"/>

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/write_et"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/send_btn"
                android:background="@drawable/text_sender_bg"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColorHint="#7EB2F5"
                android:hint="@string/type_here_chat"
                android:fontFamily="@font/comixno2_medium"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT:
As @Md. Asaduzzaman showed the problem is not in the xml.

for this xml I have a fragment with firebase realtime listener, setOnClickListener for the send button uploading a message to firebase realtime, and hide keyboard function, when you click on the send button.

Do anyone know what could make this behavior happen?

PROBLEM FOUND:
The problem was that in my Manifest I wrote `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`
so my solution was to change it to adjustResize and handle the movement of other layouts by myself.

Comment: You could try playing around with `android:lines`, `android:minLines` and `android:maxLines`, depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that, still not working.

Comment: Is the problem that the field is initially displayed as one line, and you want it to be initially displayed as multi-line?  Or is the field initially displayed as multi-line, and you want it to get bigger as the user types characters into it?

Comment: The problem is that the editText doesnt expand, it should start as one line and expand if there are multilines

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your **xml code only** like below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/write_et"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/send_btn"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColorHint="#7EB2F5"
    android:hint="type_here_chat"/>
```

And the output something like that

[image]

**N.B:** To explain with image I have added this as Answer

Comment: @YiShai, Is this your requirement or something else?

Comment: This is what it is supposed to do, but it doesnt for me, I run my on different devices and still the same problem. So as we can see the problem is not in the xml it's something else. Do you have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Did you try after removing programmatically applied code or create a sample app and try

Comment: I tried removing some code, but i have a big application so I didn't tried everything